# I want to redirect each, old URLs to its corresponding new rewritten URLs using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

After much research, I have come to the conclusion that I am stuck and need help. Here is my htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://website.com/404.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule contact contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule about display.php?id=2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule services display.php?id=4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule rss.xml?$ rss.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This successfully created a rewritten URL for each `display.php?id=` query. Now that I have both URLs, how can I permanently redirect `display.php?id=2` to `about`?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how you can do the exact opposite thing of what you've just done. Perhaps try rethinking your question and stating it in a more direct and straight-forward way? It's entirely lost on me what you're seeking help with here.

Comment: Hey @Sherif! I have successfully rewritten an old URL to clarify where exactly the URL was going. However, I now have two paths: the old query path, and the new path; I can go to each path successfully. How can I 301 redirect the old query paths to the rewritten paths so if you type the old path in the address bar it will redirect to the new path, showing the new path in the address bar?

I hope this helps!

Comment: You already have a 301 redirect in one of your rewrite rules above `RewriteRule . http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`. It's lost on me how you don't know how to create such a redirect when you've already done so. Perhaps take another look at the [Apache httpd docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) on how to use rewrite rules might refresh your memory? Or maybe just a copy/paste  the very rewrite rule you already used to do a 301 and change the source/destination parameters?

Comment: Ahh, I thought that redirect was to redirect all www to non-www. Would I have to create other redirect rules for the rewritten URLs?

Comment: It is, but it's an example of a 301 redirect. Do you not understand your own rule or did you just arbitrarily copy this from somewhere on the Internet?

Comment: This is getting nowhere. I'll wait for other replies. Thanks for trying your best to help out.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but perhaps the reason this isn't getting you anywhere is because you're stubbornly ignoring what I'm saying. To have Apache httpd send back a 301 response code as a result of a rewriterule you include the `[R]` flag setting the response code as a parameter as per the documentation I've already pointed you to and as per the same rule you've already previously used for another rewrite. I honestly can't believe you're expecting *help* beyond this point - short of walking up to your computer and rewriting it for you.

Comment: @Sherif Thanks, but you can go to another post now. Someone much nicer answered and helped me with my question.

Answer (score 0):

First off, clear your browser cache. We don't want any cached permanent redirects which you already tried messing with our new logic:

```
#remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#Use 302 redirects for debugging (the default if no redirect code is provided):
RewriteRule ^/?contact/?$ contact.php [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^/?about/?$ display.php?id=2 [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^/?services/?$ display.php?id=4 [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^/?rss.xml/?$ rss.php [NC,L,R]
```

If you're using google chrome, you can press ctrl+shift+j to open the developer tools. Then click the "network" tab and check the "disable cache" checkbox. Then try your requests again to see if it's working. Notice my code uses 302 redirects, this is the best practice for debugging. Once you can verify it's working as expected, you change change the 302 redirects to 301 redirects for production.

**Edit:**

To redirect everything the other way around, use this one instead:

```
#remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Use 302 redirects for debugging (the default if no redirect code is provided):
RewriteRule ^/?contact.php/?$ contact [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=2(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?display\.php/?$ about? [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=4(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?display\.php/?$ services? [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^/?rss.php/?$ rss.xml [NC,L,R]
```

**Edit2:**

```
#remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#handle silent rewrites first:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\s+/?about
RewriteRule ^/?about/?$ /display.php?id=2&r=%1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\s+/?contact
RewriteRule ^/?contact/?$ contact.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\s+/?services
RewriteRule ^/?services/?$ display.php?id=4 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\s+/?rss\.xml
RewriteRule ^/?rss.xml/?$ rss.php [NC,L]


#handle redirects:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\s+/?display.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=2(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?display\.php/?$ about? [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\s+/?contact\.php
RewriteRule ^/?contact.php/?$ contact [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\s+/?display\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=4(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?display\.php/?$ services? [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\s+/?rss\.php
RewriteRule ^/?rss.php/?$ rss.xml [NC,L,R]
```

**Edit3:**
Actually, we can make use of the `END` flag here for slightly cleaner code:

```
#remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#handle silent rewrites first:
RewriteRule ^/?about/?$ /display.php?id=2&r=%1 [NC,L,NS,END]
RewriteRule ^/?contact/?$ contact.php [NC,L,NS,END]
RewriteRule ^/?services/?$ display.php?id=4 [NC,L,NS,END]
RewriteRule ^/?rss.xml/?$ rss.php [NC,L,NS,END]

#handle redirects:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=2(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?display\.php/?$ about? [NC,L,R,END]

RewriteRule ^/?contact.php/?$ contact [NC,L,R,END]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=4(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?display\.php/?$ services? [NC,L,R,END]

RewriteRule ^/?rss.php/?$ rss.xml [NC,L,R,END]
```

Comment: Your redirects are the wrong way round: "how can I ... redirect `display.php?id=2` to `about`"

Comment: This part: "This successfully created a rewritten URL for each display.php?id= query." verifies for me that the user's understanding of rewrites is backwards since they're explaining the current behavior of the .htaccess they posted. Usually you want the clean URLs on the left and the PHP files on the right. Many people on stackoverflow get confused by which direction rewrites work. So I answered accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Ultimater! However, w3d was right and I would like to redirect display.php?id=2 to about. Currently, I see that the above logic redirects about to display.php?id=2. I apologize for the confusion / miscommunication; it seems like I wasn't descriptive enough in my question.

Comment: @junjun edited. If that works, change the temporary 302 redirect `R` flags to permanent redirect `R=301` for production later, but continue to use 302 redirects for development.

Comment: @Ultimater Hmm, unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried playing around with it and tried to understand it. However, wouldn't the redirect not work because the rewritten URLs are not created? I thought maybe creating the rewritten URL first, and then try redirecting the old URL to the new URL would work, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If the user types `http://example.com/about` into their address bar, the first .htaccess code would redirect them to `http://example.com/display.php?id=2`, updating the user's address bar accordingly and run the PHP file. While, if you used the second .htaccess code, the user is expected to visit `http://example.com/display.php?id=2` then they'd be redirected to `http://example.com/about` then their browser address bar would be updated accordingly. If you have no document there, then they'd get a 404 error. Unless you wish to do a silent rewrite back to display.php? Is this what you want?

Comment: @Ultimater Ahh I understand. Thanks for being so patient with me. I will play around with it and let you know if I have any questions. Cheers!

Comment: @Ultimater hello!! I played around with your suggestion. I think the reason why it doesn't work is because when ```http://example.com/display.php?id=2```redirects to ```http://example.com/about```, the about page doesn't exist. Don't we need to rewrite the about page first, and then redirect to it after?

Comment: If the `/about` page doesn't exist, would you like to add a silent rewrite to `display.php?id=2`? Or do you have another location you'd like to rewrite it to?

Comment: If I type into htaccess ```RewriteRule ^/?about/?$ display.php?id=2 [NC,L]```, I am able to go to ```/about```. What would be the next step in order to redirect the ```display.php?id=2``` page to ```about```?

Comment: I think I understood you. See my **edit2**. This type of functionality can easily create redirect loops if one's not careful. There's a few ways to avoid one. One is ENV variables, but .htaccess will rename your variables whenever a redirect is done by appending `REDIRECT_` in front of your variable names making it hard to keep track of. A solution more in the direction of human-world logic would be to grab the text of the request from the user's browser and rewrite based on that. Thus my addition of `%{THE_REQUEST}` which will yield something like `GET /about HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: I added an alternative **edit3** as well if your apache version supports the `END` flag.